How To Pull Table Data From SharePoint
CAVEATS:

I'm not a SharePoint administrator.
I have only user permissions on SharePoint
I don't/won't have access to the SharePoint API
I'm not a cURL expert

I'm trying to pull data from a table on a SharePoint page, which will be used in another application to (eventually) replace SharePoint. Because of the caveats (listed above), this seems quite a difficult task. After various searches for pulling data from a SharePoint page, I tried using cURL:
curl -XGET "https://sharepoint_domain/SitePages/:443"/page.aspx/_api -k --ssl-no-revoke -H 'Accept: application/json;odata=verbose'
Here is a part of what I'm seeing:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict/EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml11-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" lang="en-us" dir="ltr">
<head><meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA=Compatible" content="IE=8"/><meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOHTMLINDEX" /><title>

    Error

</title><link id="CssLink-6a5da1ae7871486783eef4e39b12a0dc" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/corev15.css?rev=BiOgxuWcxBnhKNutTFJcDA%3DTAG0"/><link id="CssLink-c10a92970b524de09b4caa85fcf304f7" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/10dd/styles/error.css?rev=vTz2WsuD%2F0Fcv4k2YzK4Lw%3D%3DTAG0"/><style id="SPThemeHideForms" type="text/css">body {opacity:0 !importat}</style><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[

var g_SPOffSwitches={};
// ]]>

In looking through the rest of the output, there's not a shred of the data I'm trying to pull. Obviously, this cURL statement is misconfigured or just plain wrong.
One other thing, 10-11s after this output, this error shows upon on the console:
0curl(6) Could not resolve host: application
Given the caveats listed above, is there a methdololgy to get the data from the SharePoint table?
